# Nested query get failed

Tags: soql, nested

I am trying to do nested query but getting error while saving it. Contact and opprotunity have lookup to account. So I am trying to build a nested soql using this. But getting an error while saving 
Error :

> Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Opportunity' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 7 column 19

My code :

```
public class nestedSoql{
public List<Account> accLst = new List<Account>();

public List<Account> accountChildInformation(){
     accLst = [SELECT Name, 
                     (SELECT Name 
                      FROM   Contacts 
                      LIMIT  1),
                     (SELECT Name
                      FROM   Opportunity 
                      LIMIT  1)
               FROM  Account
               WHERE Name != null];


    return accLst ;
}
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship name between Account and Opportunity is Opportunities, so you need to use that instead when writing your query.

```
[SELECT Name, 
    (SELECT Name FROM Contacts LIMIT  1),
    (SELECT Name FROM Opportunities LIMIT  1)
FROM  Account
WHERE Name != null]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you trying to access child records like this you have to use the plural form or correct relationship. Refer to `Account` object in your WSDL to clearly identify the correct relationship name. For this it should be `Opportunities'. So try below.

```
accLst = [SELECT Name, 
                     (SELECT Name 
                      FROM   Contacts 
                      LIMIT  1),
                     (SELECT Name
                      FROM   Opportunities
                      LIMIT  1)
               FROM  Account
               WHERE Name != null];
```